# table - error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables

I get an error message for a table. Strange thing is that I already have a similar table in my file, and thereby I don't get an error message... Can someone help me out?

The table is the following:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Impact on Trade Balance, in million US \$ change from base}
\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \hline\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Scenario A} \\
    \hline

               & EFTA & CA & ROW   \\[-10pt]
               &      &        &          \\




Non-Agriculture & 3.1598 & -3.9787 & 1.0283    \\

Agriculture &  -1.9159 & 3.2666 & -2.0655   \\

Services & -1.8677 & 0.3535 & 2.01962   \\\cline{2-12}

Total & -0.6238 & -0.3586 & 0.9824 \\

 \hline 
      \multicolumn{4}{l}{Scenario B} \\
    \hline 

    Non-Agriculture & 2.5389 & -3.0276 & 0.6769   \\

Agriculture &  -1.0801 & 1.9608 & -1.2893 \\

Services & -1.8290 & 0.7192 & 1.3302  \\\cline{2-12}

Total & -0.3702 & -0.3476 & 0.7178  \\

    \hline\hline
  \end{tabular}}
  \caption*{\scriptsize{Source: RunGTAP.}}
\label{tbl:EffectsOnTradeBalance}
\end{table}
```

The error message is the following:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.2510 \end{tabular}}

You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
```

Comment: Why there is `\scalebox{1}` and many empty lines?

Comment: the \scalebox function allows us to manually scale the table if it is, for instance, too wide and doesn't fit on one A4 page.... the function is getting closed with a bracket after \end{tabular} ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
\cline{2-12}
```

requests a horizontal rule to span from column 2 through to column 12. However, you only have a 4-column `tabular` since you've used

```
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
```

You're probably interested in using `\cline{2-4}`.

Comment: oh man!!!! you made my day... I've been looking for errors the whole day and couldn't find anything... maybe because I'm looking at too many tables and numbers. I somehow lost the overview!!! but you saved me!! thank you very much @Werner